# How to perform bagging of decision trees and get the accuracy using out-of-bag estimation?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am trying to perform bagging of decision trees using a number of bag sizes 200, 400, 600 to get the accuracy of each bag size using oob estimation. How would I update my code to use multiple bag sizes and from this how would I get the accuracy using oob estimation for each bag size? Here is my code so far...

```
library(ipred)
data(iris)
training_set.tree <- bagging(as.factor(Species)~., iris, nbagg=200, coob=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the OOB error rate via `$err`

```
library(ipred)
data(iris)
vals = c(200,400,600)
for(in in vals){
print(1-bagging(as.factor(Species)~., iris, nbagg=i, coob=TRUE)$err) }
```

This snippet would print the accuracy (1-classification error) for every nbagg in vals.